# Getting all VM IP addresses using vmware.vim.dl

Tags: c#, vsphere

My first post to this site after using it for a few years for finding issues I have.

I'm using vmware.vim.dll to access a vSphere host.  I'm trying to get all the IP addresses of all VM that are hosted but I seems to only be able to get the primary IP if the VM has more than one.  Is here is way to do this?

I'm using the following currently but as I indicated I only get the primary IP:

```
EntityViewBase appDC = Client.FindEntityView(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, thisDcFilter, null);
VirtualMachine thisDC = (VirtualMachine)appDC;
GuestInfo vmInfo = thisDC.Guest;
frm.lbVMstatus.Items.Add(" IP: " + vmInfo.IpAddress);
```

Is there a way to get this?

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got it.
I had to use 'GuestNicInfo' in order to get all the IP addresses on VM's that had more than one IP.

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted by clicking the grey checkmark below the downvote button. That way future visitors of this post can find the solution as fast as possible.